# LINQ - get all members of a certain type in a list of object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class holding a `Color` and a string:

```
 public class Magic{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Color MyColor {get; set;}
 }
```

I have a List of them:

```
List<Magic> MyList = new List<Magic>();
```

I'm not too experienced with LINQ and I want to know how to get all `Color` objects in the `List` into a new `List` of just the `Color`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb548891.aspx) method:

```
List<Color> magicColors = MyList
    .Select(magic => magic.MyColor)
    .ToList();
```

If you want only the *unique* colours:

```
List<Color> magicColors = MyList
    .Select(magic => magic.MyColor)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

The idea is that for every `Magic`, it will pull out its `MyColor`. That's what the `Select(magic => magic.MyColor)` does.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, and if you are looking for a projection of colors, then @ChrisSinclair answer is correct.

If, on the other hand, you want to filter by color, then you can do it like this:

```
var magicS = (from magic in MyList where magic.MyColor == s select magic).ToList();
```

or

```
var magicS = MyList.Where(m => m.MyColor == s).ToList();
```

Comment: This would _filter_ and retrieve any `Magic` objects which have their `MyColor` equal to `s`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Indeed. Which is what I think the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used the .FindAll approach.

```
var lst = GetAllProducts();

List<ProductModel> sel = lst.FindAll(x => x.IsActive == true);

return sel;
```

I have a method that gets all the products into a List<>.  My Product Model has a property called IsActive (a boolean).

This code creates a new List<> of just the Active=True products.